# How is the DEK in a SED drive encrypted?

Tags: disk-encryption, opal-2.0

I am using a Samsung Evo 960 NVME SSD. I have encrypted the SSD using its built in hardware encryption features, which follow the tcg opal standard. If I understood correctly, the disk encrypts all data using AES-256. The key for this encryption is called the DEK (disk-encryption-key). The DEK is then encrypted again, using a password provided by me.

An attacker with access to the disk could theoretically extract the (encrypted) DEK from the drive. I would like to estimate how long it would take to crack the encryption of the DEK (so basically to find out my password). Therefore, I would like to know how the DEK is encrypted using my password, so I can estimate how many passwords one could try per second on commodity hardware.

**Edit from comment:**
The question is: How is this key (the DEK) encrypted/generated? Is it a 256-bit hash of the password? If so, which hash method is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is no publicly available information about this specific model of Samsung. However disk encryption of *Samsung 840 EVO* and *Samsung 850 EVO* have been studied (among other SSD drives) in [this paper](https://www.ru.nl/publish/pages/909275/draft-paper_1.pdf). Based on the research Key derivation scheme is built upon:

***1 - Key Storage***

[image]

This key storage is aimed to validate the password and to derive the key :

> A password candidate p' is validated by computing PBKDF2(HMAC_SHA256,
>   p', Sverif). Then, the result is compared against the stored
>   PBKDF2(HMAC_SHA256, p, Sverif). If they match, then p = p' is assumed.
>   The derived encryption key is then obtained by computing
>   PBKDF2(HMAC_SHA256, p', Sderiv).

***2 - Crypto blob*** 
[image]

This bloc is 64KB and it holds all information related to disk encryption including DEK:

> From password to DEK Samsung’s Opal implementation allows a total
>   number of 9 ranges and 14 passwords to be specified. The password is
>   fed to the validation/derivation function, using slot 478+u, where u
>   is the user id associated with the password. Once the password has
>   been validated, the derived key is then used to decrypt an entry in
>   the password ↔ range mapping table. The entry is located at slot 0 +
>   27u + 3r, where u is the user id and r is the range number. Finally,
>   the decrypted result is used to decrypt slot 456+r, yielding the DEK
>   for range r

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I don't need to crack any 256-bit key. The encrypted key is right there on the drive, and I only need to find out my 10-15 character password to decrypt it. The question is: How is this key encrypted/generated? Is it a 256-bit hash of the password? If so, which hash method is used?

Comment: I edited my answer, you should have a look at the paper it will give you more insights

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This is exactly what I was looking for.